# Why the element $t \in F(t)$ is transcendental over $F$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, transcendental-numbers

While studying algebra, I came across with the following sentence:
"*The element $t \in F(t)$ is transcendental over  $F$ since if $f(t) = 0$ for some $f \in F[X]$, then necessarily $f=0$*".

Why is that?

Do not we have $g(X)=X-t \in F[X]$ so that $g(t) = 0$?

Comment: $g(X)$ is not in $F[X]$ because $t \not\in F$.

Comment: Can not we write $t$ in terms of elements of $F$?

Comment: No. $t$ is an indeterminate.

Comment: So it is just something abstract that has not any relationship with my fields.

Comment: Since I could not realise that small detail, can you suggest me a resource on field extensions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$t$ is transcendental over $F$ if and only if the map
$$\varphi : F[x] \to F[t]$$
defined by $f(x) \to f(t)$ is isomorphism. This is because $\ker(\varphi) = (m_t(x))$, where $m_t(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $t$ over $F$. So the $\ker(\varphi) = 0$ if and only if $t$ has no minimal polynomial over $F$, i.e. $t$ is transcendental.

In this case the isomorphism is clear because $F[x]$ and $F[t]$ are both the polynomial ring in one indeterminate over $F$, just with different names for the indeterminates.

Comment: Injective, not an isomorphism. And they're not the same ring; one is polynomials, the other is rational functions. (Fortunately, the two errors cancel out :) )

Comment: @darijgrinberg once you have injectivity then the fact that it is an isomorphism follows, and no, you don't consider rational functions, they are the same ring.

Comment: Well, the OP considers rational functions if he is writing $F\left(t\right)$.

Comment: @NoahRiggenbach I'm pretty sure the map $F[x] \to F[t]$, $x \mapsto t^2$ is injective but is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @darijgrinberg by the answer was establishing a criterion for an element to be transcendental, you don't need rational functions and in fact they get in the way.

Comment: @Quasicoherent yeah but that isn't the same map as $\phi$